# SQL - group & sum based on date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am little stuck on queriying particular scenario using SQL.

Say we have the following data

```
d1 - Date
d2 - Date
count - number
sum - number

    d1       d2   count     sum
20-May-14,20-May-14,117.00,201452.45
20-May-14,21-May-14,36.00,72966.37
20-May-14,22-May-14,23,30599.99
20-May-14,23-May-14,9.00,3012345.11
20-May-14,24-May-14,4,2750.46
20-May-14,25-May-14,2,2391.59
20-May-14,26-May-14,11.00,34625.52
20-May-14,27-May-14,2,2891.59
20-May-14,28-May-14,5,6188.79
21-May-14,21-May-14,84.00,192357.77
21-May-14,22-May-14,21,52805.22
21-May-14,23-May-14,13,27730.85
21-May-14,24-May-14,11.00,40361.32
21-May-14,25-May-14,4.00,7431.79
21-May-14,26-May-14,7.00,19903.92
21-May-14,27-May-14,4,6160.74
21-May-14,28-May-14,7.00,11905.57
```

I want to group and sum the data in the following manner

1. count & sum when d1=d2 (on the day of d1, e.g.: when d1 = 20-May-14, d2 = 20-May-14)
2. count & sum when d2=d1+1 (next day of d1 e.g.: when d1 = 20-May-14, d2 = 21-May-14)
3. count & sum when d2=d1+2 (day after next day of d1 e.g.: when d1 = 20-May-14, d2 = 22-May-14)
4. count & sum when d2>d1+3 (total - greater than day after next day of d1 e.g.: when d1 = 20-May-14, d2 >= 23-May-14)

I am currently using individual conditions to query a very large database based on the above result set and consolidate results manually.

Is it possible to query the data and get the results from the table as the following consolidated info:

```
d1,count(d2=d1),sum(d2=d1),count(d2=d1+1), sum(d2=d1+1), count(d2=d1+2),sum(d2=d1+2),count(d2>=d1+3),sum(d2>=d1+3)
20-May-14,117,201452.45,36,72966.37,23,30599.99,33,3061193.06
21-May-14,84,192357.77,21,52805.22,13,27730.85,33,85763.34
```

Comment: Is your prolem resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can expand the given query by adding additiobnal conditions ,this should work. Let me know if you face any issue

```
select d1,SUM(case 
               when d1=d2 then cnt 
              end
           )  as count_d1_d2,
         SUM(case 
              when d1=d2 then sm 
             end
             ) as  SUM_d1_plus_d2,
         SUM(case 
               when d2=d1+1 then cnt 
              end
           )  as count_d1_d2_1,
         SUM(case 
              when d2=d1+1 then sm 
             end
             ) as  SUM_d1_d2_1

from test
group by d1
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dc207/8)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have oracle so I cannot check syntax, but here is approximate logic:

```
select d1, least(d2-d1, 3) as type, count(*), sum(...)
from table
group by d1, least(d2-d1, 3)
```

so, logic here is to calculate difference between dates and group by it

to cover branch where (d2>d1+3) we're using least

Comment: I think that query should contain `d1` as first field